# Unexpected priority of comparison operator over null coalesce operator

Tags: php, operator-precedence, null-coalescing-operator

I don't understand why this happens:

```
$var = 'x';
var_dump($var ?? '' == 'somevalue');
```

It outputs `string(1) "x"`, while one should expect `bool(false)`.

What is the reason behind this?

---

To imagine a use case, think for example at:

```
// I want to do something only if the optional_parameter is equal to somevalue
if($_GET['optional_parameter'] ?? '' == 'somevalue') { 
    ...
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of operator precedence, try:

```
$var = 'x';
var_dump(($var ?? '') == 'somevalue');
```

More: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Plus a general advice: there is never too many parens! :) If you're not sure what is calculated first in a given language - use them!